# unable to fix Unhandled Rejection error -

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, promise

I have tried my best to locate the error. I am using the catch to handle errors though.
Could someone pls point out what I am doing wrong ?

```
const get = (query: Query) => {
    return new Promise((onSuccess, onFailure) => {
        console.log(query.url())
        fetch(query.url(), {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers(),
            mode: 'no-cors'
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) { throw Error(response.statusText) }
            onSuccess(response.json())
        }, error => onFailure({error})
        ).catch(e => onFailure(e))
    })
}
```

[image: unhandled rejection erro]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should return your fetch request in your Promise.

Also, maybe i'm wrong but this error handling is much as needed :

```
   }, error => onFailure({error})
```

You have already :

```
).catch(e => onFailure(e))
```

I think you can test it like that :

```
const get = (query: Query) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Is query.url() a request ? it can be the one which failed also.
        return fetch(query.url(), {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers(),
            mode: 'no-cors'
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) { 
               throw Error(response.statusText) 
            }
            return resolve(response.json())
        })
        .catch(e => reject(e))
    })
    // And also if the child request failed, your parent Promise will fail so you have to catch it well
    .catch(e => {console.log(e)})
}
```

EDIT: I forgot something, if you use `throw` in a child callback, it will not work for sure every times, so maybe the `.catch` after the `throw` is never called, try to use `reject` instead of `throw`.

Like this :

```
const get = (query: Query) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Is query.url() a request ? it can be the one which failed also.
        return fetch(query.url(), {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers(),
            mode: 'no-cors'
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) { 
               reject(response.statusText) 
            }
            return resolve(response.json())
        })
        .catch(e => reject(e))  //the catch will be triggered
    })
    // And also if the child request failed, your parent Promise will fail so you have to catch it well
    .catch(e => {console.log(e)})
}
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate.
Hope it will help you ^^